# React - Material UI grid items center issue

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am unable to center the elements group using **material ui grid system**.

**Issue**: The margin space on the exteme right.

> Code:

```js
const renderProjects = projects.map(project => (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} m={3} lg={3} key={project.title}>
      <ProjectCard
        title={project.title}
        description={project.description}
        image={project.image}
      />
    </Grid>
  ));

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
      justify="center" <==== Doesn't work
      alignItems="center"
    >
      { renderProjects}
    </Grid>
  )
```

And the `ProjectCard` component has only this style:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  media: {
    height: 100
  },
});
```

> Image of the grid:

[image]

I am a backend developer doing work for the client, cannot seem to figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and apparently it does work if you use `justifyContent` instead of `justify`. You don't need to add a style tag.

( MUI v5.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to provide some margin to your cards. Currently, the flex items are taking up X % of space depending on the screen size (defined by your `xs, sm, m, & lg` props), and the cards are only set to take up a maximum of `300` `width`, hence the "space to the right" depicted by the orange section on the attached image above.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 300,
    margin: "auto", // <-- add this
    marginBottom: "10px" // <-- only a suggestion. you might want to add spacing below each card
  },
  media: {
    height: 100
  },
});
```

```js
const projects = [{
  title: "sample title",
  description: "desc",
  image: "https://via.placeholder.com/300x100"
},{
  title: "sample title",
  description: "desc",
  image: "https://via.placeholder.com/300x100"
},{
  title: "sample title",
  description: "desc",
  image: "https://via.placeholder.com/300x100"
},{
  title: "sample title",
  description: "desc",
  image: "https://via.placeholder.com/300x100"
},]

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 300,
    margin: "auto",
    marginBottom: "10px"
  },
  media: {
    height: 100
  },
});

function App() {

  const renderProjects = projects.map((project, index) => (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} m={3} lg={3} key={index}>
      <ProjectCard
        title={project.title}
        description={project.description}
        image={project.image}
      />
    </Grid>
  ));

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
      justify="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      {renderProjects}
    </Grid>
  )
}

function ProjectCard({title, description, image}){

  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <Card classes={{root: classes.root}}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          classes={{media: classes.media}}
          component="img"
          image={image}
          title={title}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {description}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <!-- React -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <!-- Babel -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- MUI -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { Button, Grid, Card, CardActionArea, CardMedia, CardContent, Typography, CardActions, makeStyles } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `md` not `m` property that you used inside Grid item, change that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `style={{display:'flex'; justifyContent:'space-evenly'}}` to the grid container.